# Webpages being de-indexed seemingly for no reason

Tags: search-engine-indexing, seo, google-index

Last Wednesday my site had a ton of its paged de-indexed by Google and it's caused a drop of over 60% in overall site traffic :(... One of the pages used to rank first page #1-3 and now it doesn't even show up if I type the exact URL in the search bar.

I have tried redoing the sitemap (of which only half the pages are even being indexed - no idea why) and submitting the URLs directly. All to no avail.

I don't use any blackhat tactics for SEO, there are no manual actions, and I checked Barracuda and the drop in traffic has nothing to do with recent updates.

I'm confused as hell and so far no one has been able to help. If there's anyone out there with some bright ideas I'd really apprecaite it. Kind of panicking right now.

Comment: Welcome back!! You may want to add your screen shot. I found it useful.

Comment: The URL you posted has a different canonical tag defined. Is this a change that has been done since it was de indexed?

Comment: Heya, no, the change was made at the creation of the article. Fortunately it has since reappeared as of yesterday, however I still have about 800 articles that are de-indexed. An example of this is [http://www.citynomads.com/travel/australasia/australia/48/city-nomads-good-food-guide-to-sydney][1]

Any thoughts?

  [1]: http://www.citynomads.com/travel/australasia/australia/48/city-nomads-good-food-guide-to-sydney

Comment: I would report this on Google Webmaster's forum: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/webmasters

Comment: already did about a week ago but it seems like no one is sure what the issue is and the pages are stil de-indexed :(